# ModuleNotFoundError when I try to use pip on windows 11 command prompt

Tags: python, pip

I am new to programming, and I have Python *3.11.2*. I am trying to download *Jupyter notebook* using *pip*, but it says "*`No module named 'pip._internal'`*". I get the same error when I simply try to open *pip*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\aidan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package
```

I have been searching the internet for 2 days trying to find a solution; I have uninstalled and reinstalled Python, making sure that *pip* is selected in the customize install; I have manually added Python to the `PATH` environment variable even though it should already be there; I have read countless articles and watched countless videos describing how to do these things, but no matter what it keeps saying that there is no module named *pip*. However, if I import *pip* in the python shell, I don't get an error, so from what I can tell that means that it is installed. I do not have much coding experience, so I may be missing something.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the pip command you are running? You might just have to run: `python -m pip install ...` if pip is not in your environment variables/PATH. Another option is that you need to call `pip3`, so: `pip3 install ...` or `python3 -m pip3 install ...`.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden `python3 -m pip3` is not a thing that exists, `python3 -m pip` would be correct.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Another suggestion since you say you are new to this, installing and using [the Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) would handle all this installing the Python ecosystem, including Jupyter in a way that it will work well. (It might not come with Python 3.11 as that is pretty cutting edge and part of the point of Anaconda/conda is that it's making sure things work well together before integrating them. So the default distribution is more the tried-and-true. Yet, you can update the Python version it has after. If you search 'anaconda current python version' ...

Comment: <continued> in your favorite search engine about half of the list covers checking and the other half covers updating it.) Then you switch to using `conda` as much as possible and not `pip`. Reserve further `pip` use only for those few things that conda doesn't have a recipe for.

Comment: I ended up using Anaconda and it worked. I'm not sure what was going on before, but I appreciate you all helping me!

Answer (score 0):

##### Never install globally

You should always install packages inside virtual environments, rather than system-wide or user-wide. I see from the comments that you managed to work it out using Anaconda, that's a great option. However, if you ever want to do this using simple Python modules instead, here's how to do it on Windows:

##### Make sure python is installed

Check if you're using python 3, you can also check if pip is installed the same way and if it's in the PATH or not.

```
>python --version
>python -m pip --version
>pip --version
```

##### Create a new virtual environment

This uses the venv module to create a new virtual environment called `myenv` at a specified path.

```
>python -m venv path\to\myenv
```

##### Activate/source the virtual environment

You'll have to do this every time you open a new terminal, when you want to run the project etc. This can also be done through GUI of your code editor, to be able to execute the code using it.

```
# On CMD
path\to\myenv\Scripts\activate.bat

# On PowerShell
path\to\myenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

##### Use pip to install packages in this environment

You should now have access to pip, regardless of whether it was installed on the system, since virtual environments from the venv module have pip installed by default.

```
pip install notebook
```

You can now start a jupyter notebook session

```
jupyter notebook
```

And even install packages from within a notebook

```
!pip install numpy
```